# Numpy: расширение произведения вектора на матрицу для трёхмерного случая через тензорное произведение

Tags: python, numpy

Нужно расширить исходную операцию:

F(X) = обычное произведение вектора X формы (1, N) на матрицу (N, N) -> вектор (1, N)

для трёхмерного случая, когда появляется новая ось (для batch-ей), повторив, по сути F(X), ту же операцию, для матриц вдоль неё:

F2(X2) = произведение 3д тензора X2 формы (B, 1, N) на тензор (1, N, N) [можно дополнить до (B, N, N), клонировав] -> (B, 1, N)
Также, возможно, нужно убрать оси с 1.

То есть, примерный алгоритм был бы:

```
for i in range(b):
    vector = x2[i]
    new_vector = vector @ matrix
    result[i] = new_vector
```

Как реализовать то же самое через тензорное произведение (np.tensordot(X2, V2))?

Comment: Чем это принципиально отличается от произведения матрицы b на матрицу matrix?

Comment: B на matrix - это вектор-строка из b (правильно) на вектор-столбец из matrix (неправильно, должно быть на matrix целиком)